# Can I attend a visa appointment in an Indian state other than the one where I reside?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, applications, mumbai, ahmedabad

Italy visa appointment at VFS Mumbai is not available.  It is available at Ahmedabad as of now.

I reside in Mumbai. Is it OK to book visa appointment for Ahmedabad instead of Mumbai?

Comment: I have a friend who has same scenario with visa appointment tomorrow. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: This may well be a duplicate question but I have not yet found the other version.

Comment: What did VFS say when you asked them?

Comment: VFS Italy doesn't answer such questions. I have used all modes.. Twitter, mail,  customer  care... still left without any answer

Comment: In theory, you should apply to the consulate of your country of destination serving your place of residence (through VFS or TLS, if need be). It might be in a different place or even in a different country and might be different depending on the country of destination. In practice, I don't know exactly but I think applying to another one in the same country should be OK, especially if you can justify it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can book appointment in another state without any issues.

I had a friend who had to take Schengen Visa, residing in Kerala successfully applied in VFS Goa (on 25 August 2022). He didn't had to provide any explanation or additional documents, as its kind of self explanatory on why you want to take from a different VFS. Country: Czech Republic.

*Note: This advice applies only to Schengen visa via VFS in India. For US visa and such there are clear rules on what consulate you are supposed to apply.*

Comment: Note that there are still some restrictions at least in the case of Italy: India is apparently divided in 3 different regions, and you apparently need to apply within the right region. But you can probably apply in any center within that region. I haven't found a list of the centres for each region, though, so while some are obvious some on the edge between the regions may be a bit more of a problem.

Comment: Formally, the Schengen area has the same rule but I don't know if it matters in practice. Also, do I understand you correctly that your friend applied to Goa because that's where the Czech Republic's consulate is located? If that's the case then it's applying anywhere else that would be forbidden and this answer might not be relevant to the OP.

Comment: @Relaxed  He applied in Goa as there was no appointments in Kerala within reasonable time. He applied in VFS, not embassy. And the embassy is in New Delhi

Comment: @AnishSheela Then the situation seems very similar (+1) Maybe explaining that in the answer would make it even better? I was just wondering what you meant by “self-explanatory“ as you mentioned the country in the same paragraph. For reference: visa applications are always processed by consulates (not embassies, although many will have a consular section) and VFS (or TLS in other places) only act as a first filter based on a contract with the relevant consulate(s). The application must still make its way there somehow.

Comment: Fell free to edit the answer.